# Подключение модулей в PyCharm

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

Установил модуль `requests` для python через `PIP`.
В терминале через интерпритатор python3 всё работает:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://google.com')
>>> print(r.text)
```

А вот PyCharm не видит подключённого модуля с тем же кодом. Как дать ему знать, что он есть? 
ОС: Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Для подключения модулей перейти в File->Settings->Interpreter
2) Находим значок "+" 
3) Ищем нужный модуль, устанавливаем его. Подтверждаем изменения, перезагружаем с настройкой обнволений PyCharm 
3) Profit

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное, полчаса сидел в раздумьях почему cmd всё видит и воспроизводит (модуль ставил через pip) а pycharm не в какую не хочет. Теперь всё работает!!!

Answer (score 1):

ваш проект имеет своё виртуальное окружение venv. Туда ставятся все пакеты, что Вы хотели бы. Поэтому можно к тому варианту выше (что Вам посоветовали) так же прямо в Терминале самой IDE (а он уже будет запущен с Вашим виртуальным окружением) сделать установку необходимого пакета обычным для Вас способом:

```
(venv) xxxxx@yyyy:~/PycharmProjects/my_project$ pip ......
```

Все установленные пакеты таким образом так же будут отображены в Project Interpreter после установки из Терминала самого PyCharm с текущим виртуальным окружением Вашего проекта.